# Adding New Data Source Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I am creating a new project in visual studio 2013 and tried to connect from an existing database which I will get all the results that I needed. I have my SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and already attached the database I need, I am using a video as my reference on how to add data source on my project and it says that once the adding process was done, it will automatically add the Connection String on App.config, but after so many trials it isn't still working, I tried restarting the project, excluding the data source from the project and doing the process again, but the connection string doesn't automatically appears. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please add your c# code with this question.

Comment: Please add a link to the video you are watching.

Comment: This is the link of the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Orf_WJBXW04

Comment: Which code do I need to attach, all I have is just the form and design of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project name in the solution explorer > Add > New Item > Data > LINQ to SQL Classes > Name it > Add. Then you will see a .dbml file in the solution explorer. Double click on it > you will see a white screen, link to Server Explorer > add your database connection and choose your tables.
In your code page, just call the DataContext.
For Example;

```
DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
```